# Angular ng-Grid cell text overflow to add a cell hover menu

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid set up as a matrix with a text column and about 36 number columns.  I'm trying to create a hover popup type menu that will allow the user to add a comment to a specific cell value.  I've added a hidden div to the cell template for each cell which I can display on hover.

The issue I'm having is with the overflow of the hover menu.  The "Edit..." text is clipped off by the edges of the cell so I only see "Ed".

I've tried adding 'overflow: visible' to the cell but this hasn't worked.  Do I need to do this with javascript instead?

Comment: Demo plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2OSqkFMh6yBHAIO55M7E?p=preview (hover disabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I had to use JavaScript instead.